# AWS Step function And Athena : can I configure query string from inputpath?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, amazon-athena

in my step function, I would like to execute an Athena query. I am able to define a step and execute a query successfully. However, I would like to pass some parameters as input and use them in the query string. For example.

Let's say, my query string is:

`select * from <Data Source>.<database>.<tablename> where partition_0 = '2021';`

I want to be able to pass the year as a input json to the step function, something like:

```json
{
"YYYY": 2021
}
```

Is it possible to insert the input "YYYY" in the query string? If so, how?

Sample step function configuration:

```json
{
  "Comment": "Start athena exececution",
  "StartAt": "athena",
  "States": {
    "athena": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueryString": "select * from mycatalog.mydatabase.mytable where partition_0 = '2021'",
        "WorkGroup": "primary",
        "ResultConfiguration": {
          "OutputLocation": "s3://mys3bucket"
        }
      },
      "Next": "Pass"
    },
    "Pass": {
      "Comment": "A Pass state passes its input to its output, without performing work. Pass states are useful when constructing and debugging state machines.",
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Pass State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) to interpolate the input YYYY with the query string:

```json
"QueryPassTask": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "ResultPath": "$.athena",
  "Parameters": {
    "query.$": "States.Format('select * from mycatalog.mydatabase.mytable where partition_0 = \\'{}\\'', $.YYYY)"
  },
```

Pass task output is:

```json
{
  "YYYY": 2021,
  "athena": {
    "query": "select * from mycatalog.mydatabase.mytable where partition_0 = '2021'"
  }
}
```

Next, provide the query string to the Athena task.  Don't forget the '.$' suffix on the key.  This tells Step Functions that the key's value contains a substitution.

```json
 "Parameters": {
        "QueryString.$": "$.athena.query",
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to fedenov's answer: I think you don't necessarily need an intermediate `Pass` state. The `Pass` state also does not allow you to use the `ResultSelector` (that might be annoying). You can do the string formatting directly in the Athena Query task.

Below is an example.

```json
{
    "athena": {
        "catalog": "my_catalog",
        "database": "my_database",
        "outputLocation": "S3://my_bucket...",
        "queryString": "SELECT ... {}",
        "year": "2022"
    }
}
```

```json
    "queryData": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueryExecutionContext": {
          "Catalog.$": "$.athena.catalog",
          "Database.$": "$.athena.database"
        },
        "ResultConfiguration": {
          "OutputLocation.$": "$.athena.outputLocation"
        },
        "QueryString.$": "States.Format($.athena.queryString, $.athena.year)",
        "WorkGroup": "primary"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.query",
      "Next": "nextStep"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose my preferred clean solution using `ExecutionParameters`. You can find out more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html#athena-StartQueryExecution-request-ExecutionParameters). In your example it would look like this:

```
"queryData": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "QueryExecutionContext": {
      "Catalog.$": "$.athena.catalog",
      "Database.$": "$.athena.database"
    },
    "ResultConfiguration": {
      "OutputLocation.$": "$.athena.outputLocation"
    },
    "QueryString": "select * from mycatalog.mydatabase.mytable where partition_0 = ?",
    "ExecutionParameters.$":  "States.Array($.year)",
    "WorkGroup": "primary"
  },

  "ResultPath": "$.query",
  "Next": "nextStep"
},
```

Comment: This is a much better solution, but have you tested your example? I think it needs to be `"ExecutionParameters.$":  "States.Array($.year)"` instead, because the example gives me a syntax error.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry! Changed my proposal. You should always test it ;)